# Convergence in the $L^2$ sense in the interval $(-1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Does the geometric series $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2n}$ converges in the $L^2$ sense in the interval $(-1,1)$ ?

To Answer this question as far I can remember the use of partial sum. But don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider partial sum $$f_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x^{2n}=\frac{1-x^{2N}}{1-x^2}$$ and its point-wise limit function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ for $x\in(-1,1)$. Note that on any closed subinterval of $(-1,1)$, $f_N$ uniformly converges to $f$. Then any functions $g\in L^2(-1,1)$ such that $$\|f_N-g\|_{L^2}\to 0,\quad N\to\infty$$ should satisfy $f(x)=g(x) \text{ a.e.}$; if not so, we can find a closed subinterval $I\subset(-1,1)$ on which $M:=\|f-g\|_{L^\infty(I)}>0$ and $I_{M/2}:=\{x\in I:|f(x)-g(x)|>M/2\}$ of positive measure. Then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n>N$,
$$
f_n(x)-f(x)<M/4,\quad x\in I_{M},
$$
therefore,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|f_n-g\|_{L^2(-1,1)}^2&\geq\int_{I_{M/2}}\left[|f_n(x)-f(x)|-|f(x)-g(x)|\right]^2\text dx\\
&\geq\frac{M^2}{16}\mu(I_{M/2})>0,
\end{aligned}
$$
indecating that in no way $f_N\to g$ w.r.t. $L^2(-1,1)$. However, $f\notin L^2(-1,1)$. Thus $\{f_N\}_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ diverges in sense of $L^2(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partial sum $$f_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x^{2n}=\frac {1-x^{2N}}{1-x^2}$$

For all $x\in (-1, 1)$, this geometric series converges pointwise to $$f(x)=\frac 1 {1-x^2}$$

However, $f$ is not in $L^2([-1, 1])$, so there is no convergence in that space..